# Get a list of users followed by a particular user - SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Looking to retrieve a list of users followed by a particular user. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but any help would be much appreciated. My code in jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jchan11/3dbvagz5/

```
var followingsList = [];//array to store users you follow
var USER = "the_chanman";

SC.get("/users/"+USER+"/followings",{limit:10}, function(users){
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        //store users in followsList array
        followingsList.push(users[i].username);
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is the problem that you're seeing exactly? Errors, nothing returned?

Comment: Nothing was returned and there was a 500 Internal Server Error, but the code below fixed that. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookslike you need to use the id instead of the username.

I have changed your fiddle to that, its displaying the followers:

```
//Initialize soundcloud API with client ID
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "887b335a80f3e625454ebca548c53d96"
});
var followingsList = [];
var likesList = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var USER = "the_chanman";
    var id = 83114659;
    $("#user").html(USER);

    SC.get("/users/"+id+"/followings",{limit:10}, function(users){
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            //store users in followsList array
            followingsList.push(users[i].username);
        }
        $("#followings").html(followingsList.toString());
    });    

    SC.get("/users/"+id+"/favorites", {limit: 10}, function(tracks){
         for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
            // store tracks in likesList array
            likesList.push(tracks[i].title);
          }
        $("#likes").html(likesList.toString());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/gp9gbfba/

You may want to have a look on the resolve endpoint to still use the username as input.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve

EDIT:

I have changed the fiddle that you just need to enter the username. not fancy but hope it will help you a bit:

```
//Initialize soundcloud API with client ID
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "887b335a80f3e625454ebca548c53d96"
});
var followingsList = [];
var likesList = [];

var scdisplayname = 'bnzlovesyou';
var scurl = 'https://soundcloud.com/' + scdisplayname;   

$(document).ready(function () {
SC.get('/resolve', { url: scurl }, function(result) {  
    if(result.kind == 'user')
    {id = result.id;
     $("#user").html(result.permalink);
     getUserData(id);
    }
    else {
    alert('no valid username');
    }    
});
}); 

function getUserData(userid){    
SC.get("/users/"+id+"/followings",{limit:10}, function(users){
   for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
   //store users in followsList array
   followingsList.push(users[i].username);
   }
$("#followings").html(followingsList.toString());
});    

SC.get("/users/"+id+"/favorites", {limit: 10}, function(tracks){
   for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
   // store tracks in likesList array
   likesList.push(tracks[i].title);
   }
$("#likes").html(likesList.toString());
});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/vvp6vnbm/

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there any reason my original code using the username worked for the 'likes' but not the 'followings'? The API docs don't seem to explain this distinction.

Comment: i would call that api inconsistency. but i have updated my fiddle that you can use it just by providing the username.